# Inserting extra Title when I export a datagridview in to excel

Tags: vb.net

When I export a datagridview, I need an exported excel file with extra heading like a 'Statement report'. How can I do this ? I am getting exported excel file successfully. But I need extra titles like firm name, address, report name, etc on the top of excel sheet.

Thanks in Advance..

My code given below

```
 Private Sub ExportToExcel()
        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim oValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        Dim sPath As String = String.Empty

        Dim dlgSave As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dlgSave.DefaultExt = "xls"
    dlgSave.Filter = "Microsoft Excel|*.xls"
    dlgSave.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath

        If dlgSave.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(oValue)
        xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Dim xlRow As Long = 2
                Dim xlCol As Short = 1
        For k As Integer = 0 To DGVStatement.ColumnCount - 1

                    xlSheet.Cells(1, xlCol) = DGVStatement(k, 0).Value

                    xlCol += 1

                Next

                 Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = True
                Me.ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
                Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = DGVStatement.Rows.Count

                For M = 0 To DGVStatement.RowCount - 2
                    For N = 0 To DGVStatement.ColumnCount - 1
                        For P As Integer = 1 To DGVStatement.Columns.Count
                            xlSheet.Cells(1, P) = DGVStatement.Columns(P - 1).HeaderText
                            xlSheet.Cells(M + 2, N + 1) = DGVStatement(N, M).Value.ToString()
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
                xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
                Dim sFileName As String = Replace(dlgSave.FileName, ".xlsx", "xlx")

                xlSheet.SaveAs(sFileName)

                xlBook.Close()

                xlApp.Quit()

                releaseObject(xlApp)
                releaseObject(xlBook)
                releaseObject(xlSheet)

                Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
                Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = False

                 MsgBox("Data successfully exported.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "PRMS/SOB Date Tagging")
            Catch
                MsgBox(ErrorToString)
            Finally

            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: you should probaply leave some rows blank at the top of the page and then edit them to show what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works for you. **Edited:**

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Dim sPath As String = String.Empty

    Dim dlgSave As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dlgSave.DefaultExt = "xls"
    dlgSave.Filter = "Microsoft Excel|*.xls"
    dlgSave.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath

    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(oValue)
            xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
            Dim xlRow As Long = 2
            Dim xlCol As Short = 1

            'Header information
            xlSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "ABC EXPORTS AND IMPORTS"
            xlSheet.Cells(2, 3) = "STATEMENT REPORT"

            For k As Integer = 0 To DGVStatement.ColumnCount - 1
                xlSheet.Cells(4, xlCol) = DGVStatement(k, 0).Value
                xlCol += 1
            Next

            Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = True
            Me.ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
            Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = DGVStatement.Rows.Count

            For M = 0 To DGVStatement.RowCount - 2
                For N = 0 To DGVStatement.ColumnCount - 1
                    For P As Integer = 1 To DGVStatement.Columns.Count
                        xlSheet.Cells(4, P) = DGVStatement.Columns(P - 1).HeaderText
                        xlSheet.Cells(M + 5, N + 1) = DGVStatement(N, M).Value.ToString()
                    Next
                Next
            Next

            xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
            Dim sFileName As String = Replace(dlgSave.FileName, ".xlsx", "xlx")

            xlSheet.SaveAs(sFileName)
            xlBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()

            releaseObject(xlApp)
            releaseObject(xlBook)
            releaseObject(xlSheet)

            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Me.ProgressBar1.Visible = False

            MsgBox("Data successfully exported.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "PRMS/SOB Date Tagging")
        Catch
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)
        Finally

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```